# How to scale what has already been drawn on a canvas

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, graph, image-resizing

I made a graphing software.  But when I zoom in, it becomes laggy because I redraw the screen alot.  Could I do the same thing as this page:http://fooplot.com/

When they zoom out, it expands or contracts the predrawn graph, and then redraws when we stopped zooming in.

`.scale(2,2);` does not seem to scale anything at all.  my graph is drawn entirely by using:
ctx.fillRect();

tell me if you need the code

Comment: scale(2,2) should scale things up. I'm puzzled about the fact you mention that it does nothing.

Comment: it does not scale what has already been drawn, but rather it only scales what you draw after executing it

Comment: It is rather a good thing that scaling has no such effect ! anyway @markE's answer is ok, except maybe that you can do the whole translation+scaling by a single call to the 9 argument version of drawImage, without saving/restoring the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can "fast zoom" using the canvas as its own source for drawImage:

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/Yyc5G/

```
var zoom=2;

function zoom(){

    ctx.save();

    ctx.translate(canvas.width/2,canvas.height/2);  // or your desired zoom point

    ctx.scale(zoom,zoom);

    ctx.drawImage(canvas,-canvas.width/2,-canvas.height/2); 

    ctx.restore();

}
```

Which will do your fast zooming (yes, with jaggies).

Then when the user stops zooming you can do your better quality redraw.